# iOS: Can a UIView know that the layout process for it has completed?

Tags: ios

When using `auto layout`, the view's size is unknown when it is initialised, this brings a problem to me.

When using `UIImageView`, I wrote a category that can load image from my own `CDN` by setting the image URL to `UIImageView`, my `CDN` stores one image with different sizes so that difference devices can load the size it really needs.

I want to make my `UIImageView` be able to load the URL for the resolution it needs, but when my `UIImageView` get the URL, the size of it is not yet determined by `auto layout`.

So is there a way for UIView to know that the layout process for it has finished for the first time?

Answer (score 6):

there is a method for UIView.You could override it.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    CGRect bounds =self.bounds;
    //build your imageView's frame here
    self.imageView=imageViewFrame.
}
```

**In Swift 5.X**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let myFrame = = self.bounds
}
```

If you have other complex items in the custom view, don't forget to call super if you override `layoutSubviews()`...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no straightforward way that a UIView can be notified that its constraints have been set. You can try a bunch of different things though,

Implement `layoutSubviews` function of a `UIView`, this is called whenever `UIView`'s layout is changed.

Implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the `UIViewController` that has it inside it. This function is called when all the layouts have been set. At this point you can your category function.

Answer (score -2):

here's a test, I only use autolayout and I only use custom subclassed subviews. I do all auto layout in the initializer of the subclass:

This is for a "login button" that has no frame but is then set with autolayout:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (self.contentView.loginButton.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews");
    }
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (self.contentView.loginButton.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"viewWillLayoutSubviews");
    }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.contentView.loginButton.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"didAppear");
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.contentView.loginButton.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.contentView.loginButton.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    }
}
```

Here's the output. So, this means that my view finally has a frame when the

> 2015-08-25 01:28:27.789 [67502:1183631] viewDidLayoutSubviews
>
> 2015-08-25 01:28:27.790 [67502:1183631] viewWillLayoutSubviews
>
> 2015-08-25 01:28:27.790 [67502:1183631] viewDidLayoutSubviews
>
> 2015-08-25 01:28:28.007 [67502:1183631] didAppear

This means that the first time the login button has a frame is in the viewDidLayoutSubviews, this will look weird becuase this is the first pass of main view's subviews. There's no frame in ViewWillAppear although the view of the viewcontroller itself is already set before the login button. The entire UIView subclass's main view is also set when the viewcontroler's view is set, this happens before the login button as well. So, the subviews of the view are set after the parent view is set.

The point is this: if you plop the imageview information pull in the viewDidLayoutSubviews then you have a frame to work with, unless you set this UIImageView frame to the view of the ViewController by type casting then you will have the UIImageView's frame set in the viewDidLoad. Good luck!

Comment: Well thats cool and stuff, but  `UIView` != `UIViewController`